# Using YALMIP and Sedumi to solve large number of Constraints

Tags: matlab

I have the following problem to solve:
[image]

Im using YALMIP to define the constraints in the following way:

```
C = [7.8*10^5 0 ; 0 6.3*10^7];
D = [62500 0 ; 0 62500];

tf1 = 15;
tf2 = 15;
T = 10;

X{1} = sdpvar(2,2);
Constraints=[X{1} >= inv(C)];

for k = 1:1:T/dt

    L{k} = sdpvar(1,2);
    X{k} = sdpvar(2,2);
    X{k+1} = sdpvar(2,2);

    A{k} = [2/(tf1-t) 0 ; 0 2/(tf2-t)]; 
    B{k} = [-1/(tf1-t);-1/(tf2-t)];

    Constraints = [Constraints, -X{k+1}+X{k}+dt*(X{k}*A{k}'+B{k}*L{k})<0, X{k} < inv(D)];
    t=t+dt;

end

options = sdpsettings('Solver','Sedumi');
solvesdp(Constraints,[],options);
```

What I did is basically made a for loop that will make me a large number of constraints. 
The final result i get is a list of 2001 constraints made of 1 (`X(0)`) and another 2000 of 2 in each loop.

My question is how can I check my LMI's and see how matlab generated them using YALMIP?

I want to be able to use something like `info` to see the following:

`Constraints{1} : X{1} >= inv(C)`

`Constraints{2} : -X{2}+X{1}+dt*(X{1}*A{k}'+B{1}*L{1})<0`

`Constraints{3} : X{2} < inv(D)`

`Constraints{4} : -X{3}+X{2}+dt*(X{2}*A{2}'+B{2}*L{2})<0`

`Constraints{5} : X{3} < inv(D)`
... and so on

Thank you